# Can I use a PS4 Playstation Move controller on a PS3?

Tags: ps3, ps4, playstation-move

A friend gifted me a game and I don't have a move controller. I tried to buy one, but they told me that the move controller for ps3 is out of production now.

Can I use a PS4 Playstation Move controller on the PS3?

Answer (score 2):

The newer micro USB ones specifically made for the PS4 aren't backwards compatible. The slightly older repackaged, rereleased PS3 ones with the mini USB are though, since they are just the PS3 ones in a different box.

Here's some more info: https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2017/10/3/16411466/sony-ps-move-controller-mini-usb-micro-playstation-vr